# Can I add a blog subfolder to my website and use a different theme

Tags: themes, blog

I asked this question over at WebMasters, and was directed to this stack exchange, I might add I had no idea this even existed!

I was wondering if I am able to create a new subfolder named blog on my site, and use a different theme on the blog than my site.

Comment: Have you already seen WordPress Multisite/Network?

Answer (score 0):

The same WordPress install can only use one Theme at any one time. In order to have one Theme on `{root}` and a different Theme on `{root}/blog`, you would have to have either:

1. Separate WordPress installs at `{root}` and `{root}/blog`
2. A WordPress Multisite Network at `{root}`, with a subfolder-based network and a network site at `{root}/blog`

Comment: Are either methods advisable? It seems the easiest method would be option 1. On the other hand a wordpress multisite network sounds interesting, however I must admit I know nothing about it, and was not even aware of it. I might have to do a little research into that one.